# Google Cloud SSD Usage is being used with no VMs, disks or deployments, preventing starting new instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, solid-state-drive

My quita says I am using 400 out of 500 of GB of Persistent SSD volume inus-west-1 region, which prevents me from starting a GPU instance which requires 200G of space.

[image]

However, I have no instances running, no deployments and do no disks so I ave no idea where this usage is coming from. I did try to start a couple of GPU VM instances before but they did not go through because of resource availability, not sure if this coudld be the reason and somehow they are using this space, but not showing up anywhere in the instance window:
[image]

[image]

[image]

When I refresh VM instances, I get these failed VM instances (no resources were available) that just keep spinning under `In use by` and I can't delete them

[image]

Comment: Your post does not show disk usage. Regarding the In Use By issue, flush the browser cache and reboot your system.

Answer (score 0):

You can do verification and review as explained below :

You may do a [disk gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/list) via cloud console on your project to list compute disks as follows:

```
gcloud compute disks list
```

You may also try to run a logging query to verify create or delete or disks as follows

Disk Created

```
resource.type="gce_disk"
protoPayload.methodName:"compute.disks.insert"
log_id("cloudaudit.googleapis.com/activity")
```

Disk Deleted

```
resource.type="gce_disk"
protoPayload.methodName:"compute.disks.delete"
log_id("cloudaudit.googleapis.com/activity")
```